# mysql using cast to duplicate column var to int

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, duplicates

by mistake I cteated a column as var(45) and when I export the table to cvs I don't see the numbers .

now I want to make it as integer 
when I use this command :

```
select cast(SIM as signed) 
from sample.table1
```

I don't get any error - so I guess it convert it to int, right? 
but how do I copy the new data to the new column ?

I have try this :

```
update 
sample.table1
set SIM_NEW=cast(SIM as signed)
where id=id
```

but it doesn't work

Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'SIM_NEW' at row 1

so what am I doing wrong?

- all the data in the SIM column is a 19 digit number
- the SIM_NEW column is INT(20)

Thanks ,

Comment: How are you exporting your data to CSV?  It's never a good thing to store numeric data as text, but if you've captured all information, this shouldn't be affecting your CSV output (I think).

Comment: this is the problem - when I export it to cvs I get 9E+18 (8997250400003120000) which is not the real SIM number..... So I though that if I save it as int and not string it will fix the problem

Comment: To contradict what I said above, may I suggest that you just use `varchar` for the column type?  While the SIMs are numeric, you're probably not going to do any arithmetic or numeric comparisons with them.  They are large, but, a text column should have no trouble at all with them.

Comment: Yes , I'm not going to do any arithmetic  with them - but my problem is that when i export as cvs I don't get the number.... so how do I fix this ?

Comment: No...if you store them as plain text, you'll get plain text in the export.

Comment: So how can I store them as number and export the table and see this column as number?

Comment: Maybe you miss what I am saying.  I am saying to just store them as _text_.  Then, the export should work.

Comment: I have define the new colom as text(20) , and use the cast(SIM as char) - and it didn't give me any errors ---> but when I export I still don't see the data correct  9E+18 (8997250400003120000)

Comment: I have in mind that you will reimport your SIM data from the original external source into a text column which is wide enough to support it.

Comment: and if I will do this it will work? I can't copy the old value some how?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I have enter reimport the data to the colomn (which is datatype = tinytext) - still when I export it to cvs - I get 9E+18 and not a normal string

Comment: I found a hard way to get it - need to export as text file , then open in excel and then tell him that all the columns are text and not general...... MUST be a better way to do this ???

Comment: I still don't know exactly what you are doing here.  AFAIK, if you have a text column in SQL Server and you export it, you should get _exactly_ the text which was in the column, barring some weird encoding stuff happening.

Comment: this is what is strange , I have a tinytext colomn - reenter to it the string. when I export as cvs - I get 9E+18.  try it and see....

Comment: Also, why are you using tinytext?  Is that column wide enough to store the entire number?

Comment: yes , the max length on the sim is 20 chars

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the data type of `SIM_NEW` is `INTEGER`.

You are getting error due to range. Integer cannot handle 17 digit number. Use `DOUBLE` or any other datatype suited for the need, instead of `INTEGER` while creating `SIM_NEW` column.

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=749ab47c1f35814ed4c8496a1897cc92)

Comment: Still not good - Now I'm getting this number 8.99725040000312e18

Comment: Definitely not doubles, they are not meant for storing integers and will lose numbers at some point.

Comment: so how to define them?